# Why is a SurfaceView in a Fragment still visible when the Fragment is hidden?

Tags: android, android-fragments, surfaceview

Just a general question: I have a Fragment which has a SurfaceView. When I hide the Fragment by the FragmentManager, the SurfaceView is still visible.

I found a workaround by just setting the View to INVISIBLE/GONE/VISIBLE when the Fragment is hidden/visible - but I'm wondering: Why is the SurfaceView still shown? Is it because the SurfaceView basically is a "punched hole", which means, it's not in the Layout-Hierarchy of the Fragment and therefore can't be hidden when the Layout is hidden?

What is the hiding-procedure doing with the Fragment? Does it simply sets the created view to gone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `SurfaceView` creates an entirely separate graphics layer, composited by the system.  The "hole" is included in the view hierarchy so the layout comes out right.  There's a lot of things that don't quite work right when `SurfaceView` is involved.

A `TextureView`, by contrast, is actually part of the View itself, and will act appropriately.  The disadvantage is that there's an extra step where pixels are copied from an off-screen buffer into the view.  This is done by the GPU, so it's very fast, but if you're trying to animate a large portion of the screen at 60fps or minimize battery drain while playing a full-length movie then `SurfaceView` may be a better choice.

If using a `TextureView` is an option, doing so may make your life a bit simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I would use the TextureView but afaik there is no "GLTextureView" for Android Api > 8 available yet (well, there might be some open source, but I rather stick to "tested" code)

Comment: Ah.  There's no `TextureView` at all until API 14, so if you need to run on 2.x it's not an option.  According to http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html you potentially reach another 23% or so by targeting the older API level.